# Match a range of rows in an array? jQuery, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

*I'm unsure how else to write the title but it's about as close as I can get to what I'm after.*

I have a calculator I'm trying to create that compares values in a number of arrays.

Each data object in my array has 34 rows, some of which have the same number/value in them.

At the minute if you select france, I only want 1 of each grade to show in the dropdown, so the number 1 would appear once.

If you select `France` and grade `1`, I want the outputted value to say the lowest value in that range to the highest, in this case USA would output `3 to 5` does this make sense?

[image]

If so I'm wondering how I'd possibly do this?

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/R85Qj/

Comment: It would be easier to do if you add a numeric index to each row like ["3", "3", 3]

Comment: Thanks @NadeemAfana, I don't quite follow however, I've never used something like that

Comment: do you just need the grade drop down to be unique or is your q more complicated than that?

Comment: The grades have some sort of correlation, if you look at both arrays i the picture, In france, 1 is equal to 3 all the way up to 5.0 @RossG

Comment: If you add an extra number to each array:
    grades: [
     ["1", "1", 1],
     ["1", "1", 1],
     ["1", "1", 1],
     ["2", "2", 2],
    ]
you would be able to group matching values. This would make it easier to get unique list of your grades.

Comment: How will that benefit me though @NadeemAfana? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: which is lower "5.10a" or "5.10c"? Comparing text is not recommended in this case. It would be nice if we could give "5.10a" a value of 5 and "5.10c" a value of 6. This way 5 < 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

http://jsfiddle.net/R85Qj/2/

```
$("#convert").on("click", function () {
    var gradeIndex = $("#grade").val();
    var gradeConversion = "";
  /*  gradeConversion += "<span>" + countryGrades[countryGradesIndex].country + ": " + countryGrades[countryGradesIndex].grades[gradeIndex][1] + "</span>";*/
    var indexes = [];
    var countryIndex = $("#country").val();   
    var gradeValue = countryGrades[countryIndex].grades[gradeIndex][0];

    // find all indexes of gradeValue
    for(var i = 0; i < countryGrades[countryIndex].grades.length; i++) {
        if (countryGrades[countryIndex].grades[i][1] == gradeValue) {
             indexes.push(i);   
        }
    }

    allValues = [];

    for(var c = 0; c < countryGrades.length; c++) {
        gradeConversion += countryGrades[c].country + ":";
    for(i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || countryGrades[c].grades[indexes[i]][1] !=  countryGrades[c].grades[indexes[i-1]][1]) {
       gradeConversion += countryGrades[c].grades[indexes[i]][1] + " ";
        }
    }
   }


    $("#conversions").html(gradeConversion);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @NadeemAfana, it's not what I'm after however, I'll try and explain better.

Comment: If you select 1 in french, 1 is equal to USA 3, 4 and 5. So when you select French 1 it should output USA 3 to 5, does this make sense?

Comment: Thats halfway there @NadeemAfana! I just need to only show 1 value if theres multiple instances of it, so in france dropdown, there should be three `1` grades, just the 1

Comment: It does but the grades no longer matchup @NadeemAfana :(